# Remove horizontal and vertical scrollbar from facebook apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps

I have created a facebook apps. It works fine for me. But my problem is that always show vertical and horizontal scrollbar, when I use fluid for both width and height of my page from facebook settings. My page looks like this http://karen.webmascot.com/fb/fbone.jpg. What can I do now?

Comment: have you try to set your canvas setting width as fixed, and height is settable ?

Comment: If you are using Chrome there is a known issue where the facebook page itself (not the iFrame) actually has a horizontal scrollbar. They haven't fixed it yet. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/182748101891780

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `scroll=no` and `overflow:hidden` to your body and use [FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/) to remove the scrollbar.

```
<body scroll="no" style="overflow:hidden">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()
    }, 250)
};
(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e)
}());
</script>
```

Comment: Empty scroll bar always showing for mozilla firefox browser, not in IE.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `overflow:hidden` in your body CSS style.